# Editing records in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysqli

So am getting further into my learning and have ran into an issue with this:

Updating records from my index page, I am able to insert and delete but struggling to update them.

So this show the records with links to update or delete:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items");

$y = 'id';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['added'] . $row['content']   . $row[$y];

  echo "<br>";

  echo "Mark as complete";

  echo "<br>";

  echo "<a href='delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Delete Item</a>";

  echo "<br>";

  echo "<a href='update.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit Item</a>";    

  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";     

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When the user clicks on edit it passes over the id of that item which is good but my form to update the records is behaving strangely, the submit button seems to have disappeared but does appear if I remove the php, here is the update form:

```
<form action="insertupdate.php" method="post">
Content: <input type="text" name="content">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value='<?php $_POST ('id'); ?>'>
<button>dsfsd</button>
</form>
```

And here the script for updating, but it does not appear to be making the changes:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE items SET content='blah blah blah' WHERE id=id");

if (isset($_POST['content'])) {
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE items SET content='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content'])."' WHERE id=".($_POST['id']));
}

header('Location: index.php');

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: A bit of error checking will help you a lot. Also you are vulnerable to SQL injection trough `$_POST['id']`.

Comment: I am learning php currently so I am fairly new. Security is not an issue currently as this is a local project for me to learn.

Comment: For debugging purposes, print the MySQL error messages by adding the following after your query: `or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value='<?php $_POST ('id'); ?>'>
<button>dsfsd</button>
```

By

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Valid" />
```

You script don't get ID, so it will never work.

For your query :

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE items SET content = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content'])."' WHERE id = ".intval($_POST['id']));
```

[`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) will convert `$_POST['id']` into a number, so you will be sure a string or special character will not be entered.

Comment: and does the php in the updating file look incorrect?

Comment: Good eye there. Now the question is how did OP even test the button, given that his code should fail with a fatal error.

Comment: The strange thing is, I have applied your changes but it still dosnt update the record? I must be missing something quite key here.

Comment: @stack, are you sure that you actually receive the id by POST here: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>" />`

Comment: Well, if it shows it in the URL - receieve it by $_GET then. Surely if you outout by `echo $_POST['id']` you will see nothing while `echo $_GET['id']` will display the data for you.

Comment: How do you mean? Could you show me an example in my code?

Comment: Well, like this: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/>`. When working with FORM data you should defientely start with `$_POST` and `$_GET`, learn how they work and what their differences are.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get errors like this all the time. Fortunately, there is some very good error handling in MySQL. Add this else condition in the if with the query:

```
   if (isset($_POST['content'])) {
       mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE items SET content='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content'])."' WHERE id='".($_POST['id'])."'");
   } else {
       mysqli_error($con);
   }
```

Oh and to directly fix your problem, it looks like you need quotes around the id part of the query:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE items SET content='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content'])."' WHERE id='".($_POST['id'])."'");
```

Comment: Hm, my script still isnt updating the record, it is passing over the id, it shows no errors but still not changing the content of the item...